# in R - pass value from loop to function for function use later

Tags: r, function, loops

I calculate a new value in every iteration of a loop. This value is passed on to a function list (it is basically the coefficient for x in the corresponding function). The code I had in mind is this:

```
func_list <-list()
variable_list <-list()
for (i in 1:3){
    variable[[i]] <- calculated.value
    func_list[[i]]<- function(x){ variable[[i]] * x}
}
```

However, it does not work. The problem is that all functions will have the actual "relative reference" to variable[[i]] in the respective list position, no matter if I call func_list[[1]],func_list[[2]], or func_list[[3]] . That is, if I want to call the different functions later (which will be applied to different columns), then it only calls the last stored variable[[3]].
I guess a different way to formulate the problem is: how can I pass the calculated absolute values of each loop iteration to the functions? (such that I basically would not need the variable[[i]] list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need what are called closures - R gets non-local variables from the scope when the function was defined.  So if you wrap your function in another function, that will store variables (below, I've called it y - presence of global variables called y should not affect the behaviour in any way) that are accessible to the inner function, and return the function (which now has access to stored variables):

```
#outside the loop:
wrapper <- function(a) {y<- a
                function(x) {y*x}
           }
#inside the loop
func_list[[i]] <- wrapper(variable[[i]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would calculate each step individually.

```
variable <- sapply(1:3, FUN = function(x) rnorm(1))
func_list(variable, FUN = function(y, x) y * x, x = x)
```

Or if `x` is also a list (and not a constant), you can use `mapply`.

```
mapply(FUN = function(y, x) y * x, y = variable, x = x)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Roman - particularly for the prompt reply! I must admit that used Gavin's answer below since it may be easier to track in my code (the actual function I pass to the function list is a bit more complex, and so is the function to calculate the coefficients -hence, having an "external wrapper" helps to keep the overview). Otherwise, quick and excellent solution - thanks again!